# How to format json response in django?

Tags: django, jsonresponse

I am retrieving data from multiple tables in Django.
 my current response is :

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "message": "Client details retrived successfully...!!!",
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "client_id": "CL15657917080578748000",
            "client_name": "Pruthvi Katkar",
            "client_pan_no": "RGBB004A11",
            "client_adhar_no": "12312312313",
            "legal_entity_name": "ABC",
            "credit_period": "6 months",
            "client_tin_no": 4564565,
            "client_email_id": "abc@gmail.com",
            "head_office_name": "ABC",
            "office_name": "asd234",
            "office_email_id": "zxc@gmail.com",
            "office_contact": "022-27547119",
            "gst_number": "CGST786876876",
            "office_country": "India",
            "office_state": "gujrat",
            "office_district": "vadodara",
            "office_taluka": "kachh",
            "office_city": "vadodara",
            "office_street": "New rode 21",
            "office_pincode": 2344445,
            "contact_person_name": "prasad",
            "contact_person_designation": "DM",
            "contact_person_number": "456754655",
            "contact_person_email": "asd@gmail.com",
            "contact_person_mobile": "5675545654",
            "created_at": "2019-08-14T14:08:28.057Z",
            "created_by": "Prathamseh",
            "updated_at": "2019-08-14T14:08:28.057Z",
            "updated_by": "prasad",
            "is_deleted": false
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "user_id": "CL15657917080578748000",
            "bank_details_id": "BL15657917080778611000",
            "bank_name": "Pruthvi",
            "branch": "vashi",
            "ifsc_code": "BOI786988",
            "account_number": 56756765765765,
            "account_name": "Pruthvi",
            "is_deleted": false
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "document_details_id": "DL15657917080808598000",
            "user_id": "CL15657917080578748000",
            "document_type": "Pruthvi ID",
            "document": "www.sendgrid.com/pan",
            "is_deleted": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected Response :

[image]

I am getting the queryset form db in models.py and i am sending it to the views.py and i am iterating over the dict but not getting the expected response.

> views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def get_client_details(request):
    try:
        # Initialising lists for storing results
        result      =   []
        temp_array  =   []
        # Getting data from request body
        client_master_dict = json.loads(request.body)
        # Response from get client data
        records = ClientDetails.get_client_data(client_master_dict)
        # Create response object
        # Iterating over the records object for getting data
        for i in range(len(records)):
            # Converting the querysets objects to json array format
            record_result_list  = list(records[i].values())
            # If multiple records are present
            if(len(record_result_list) > 1):
                for j in range(len(record_result_list)):
                    user_info = record_result_list[j]
                    temp_array.append(user_info)
                result.append(temp_array)   
                temp_array=[] 
            # For single record     
            else:
                result.append(record_result_list[0])
        # Success  
        returnObject = {
            "status"    :   messages.SUCCESS,
            "message"   :   messages.CLIENT_RETRIVE_SUCCESS,
            "results"   :   result
        }
        return JsonResponse(returnObject,safe=False)
```

I think the issue might be in my inner for loop, can anyone help me out with this, is there any way to iterate over the nested JSON object.

> Models.py

```
@classmethod
    def get_client_data(cls, client_master_dict):  
        try:        
            response_list = []
            client_id = client_master_dict['client_id']
            client_details = cls.objects.filter(client_id = client_id,is_deleted = False)
            bank_details = BankDetails.objects.filter(user_id = client_id,is_deleted = False)
            document_details = DocumentDetails.objects.filter(user_id = client_id,is_deleted = False)
            response_list.append(client_details)
            response_list.append(bank_details)
            response_list.append(document_details)
            return response_list
        except(Exception) as error:
            print("Error in get_client_data",error)
            return False
```

Here i'm fetching data from 3 tables and adding it into list.

After printing the data on console i am getting :

```
[{'id': 11, 'client_id': 'CL15657917080578748000', 'client_name': 'Pruthvi Katkar', 'client_pan_no': 'RGBB004A11', 'client_adhar_no': '12312312313', 'legal_entity_name': 'ABC', 'credit_period': '6 months', 'client_tin_no': 4564565, 'client_email_id': 'abc@gmail.com', 'head_office_name': 'ABC', 'office_name': 'asd234', 'office_email_id': 'zxc@gmail.com', 'office_contact': '022-27547119', 'gst_number': 'CGST786876876', 'office_country': 'India', 'office_state': 'gujrat', 'office_district': 'vadodara', 'office_taluka': 'kachh', 'office_city': 'vadodara', 'office_street': 'New rode 21', 'office_pincode': 2344445, 'contact_person_name': 'prasad', 'contact_person_designation': 'DM', 'contact_person_number': '456754655', 'contact_person_email': 'asd@gmail.com', 'contact_person_mobile': '5675545654', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 14, 14, 8, 28, 57874, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by': 'Prathamseh', 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 14, 14, 8, 28, 57874, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by': 'prasad', 'is_deleted': False}]
[{'id': 11, 'user_id': 'CL15657917080578748000', 'bank_details_id': 'BL15657917080778611000', 'bank_name': 'Pruthvi', 'branch': 'vashi', 'ifsc_code': 'BOI786988', 'account_number': 56756765765765, 'account_name': 'Pruthvi', 'is_deleted': False}]
[{'id': 10, 'document_details_id': 'DL15657917080808598000', 'user_id': 'CL15657917080578748000', 'document_type': 'Pruthvi ID', 'document': 'www.sendgrid.com/pan', 'is_deleted': False}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the output of record_result_list? You can outright tell their if it's recovering the data in the format you requested. Try the printing to screen method to debug.

As far as I cam see, the expected output and the hierarchy of results for bank details are not matching. I don't know how you are handling the hierarchy. Are you directly taking it from JSON as the hierarchy? Or are you just taking the data and creating hierarchy in the expected output?